# How can i shorten this code?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If Label1.Text.Length = 13 Then
        Label1.Text = "Working magic."
    ElseIf Label1.Text.Length = 14 Then
        Label1.Text = "Working magic.."
    ElseIf Label1.Text.Length = 15 Then
        Label1.Text = "Working magic..."
    ElseIf Label1.Text.Length = 16 Then
        Label1.Text = "Working magic"
    End If

End Sub
```

The code basically acting as a progressive string, where every 500 milliseconds a dot will add to the string, until 3 dots where it resets.

If I wanted to do more dots then it would be nice to automate the process, instead of writing an infinite number of lines of code.

Comment: Take `label1.text = label1.text & "."` as a Building Block ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to shorten your code you could do something like this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        (Label1.text += ".").Replace("....","")
End Sub
```

However I'm convinced that shorter is not always better!

Edit: Sorry my mind goes straight to c#, here is some VB::

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
         Label1.text = (Label1.text + ".").Replace("....","")            
End Sub
```

Comment: Shortest code answered, works, and I can see how to implement in future. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code:

```
len = Label1.Text.Length - 12
str = "Working magic"

while(len>0 && len<4){
    str = str & "."
    len--;
}
Label1.Text = str
```

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code that takes into account the variable number of dots in a row.

```
final NUM_DOTS = 3  //this is your variable number of dots
len = Label1.Text.Length - 12
str = "Working magic"
numDots = NUM_DOTS

while(len){
    if (numDots == 0) {
        str = str.substring(0, str.length-NUM_DOTS);
        numDots = NUM_DOTS;
    }
    else {
        str = str & "."
        len--;
        numDots--;
    }
}
Label1.Text = str
```

Answer (score 1):

easy, console apps demo

```
Module Module1

   Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(Magic(New String("A"c, 13).Length))
    Console.WriteLine(Magic(New String("A"c, 14).Length))
    Console.WriteLine(Magic(New String("A"c, 15).Length))
    Console.WriteLine(Magic(New String("A"c, 16).Length))
    Console.Read()

End Sub

Private Function Magic(ByVal len As Integer) As String
    Dim result = "Working magic"
    Select Case len
        Case 13 To 15
            result = result & New String("."c, len - 12)
    End Select

    Return result
End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using animated GIFs like those generated here: http://www.ajaxload.info/

Try Google Search for more options: "animated gifs generator"

Just use the GIF in a picture box and use .Enable/.Visible to manage.

The animation can be stalled if the main thread is busy - probably true for the above cases as well.

Comment: Thanks, will use this in future!

Answer (score 0):

Keep the count of dots to print as a global variable, then at every call of the timer event increment this value and reset it if it reaches the upper limit.

Create a string of dots based on the current count and append it to the static label

```
Private dotCount As Integer = 0
Const MAX_DOTS = 3 


Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    if dotCount > MAX_DOTS Then
        dotCount = 0
    End If
    Label1.Text = "Working magic" & new String(".", dotCount)
    dotCount = dotCount + 1
End Sub
```

If you want to print more dots, just change the constant used as upper limit (MAX_DOTS)